# New to python, delete and delimit

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and trying to help my team.  In short we have a csv file, 3 columns wide.
First column has no name and is blank, second column needs to be delimited, thrid column can be deleted.  Additionally the first row needs to be deleted as the header row needed for the delimited is in row 2.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
# read_csv function which is used to read the required CSV file 
data = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')  

# display  
print("Original 'myfile.csv' CSV Data: \n") 
print(data) 
data = data.loc[:, ~data.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
# drop function which is used in removing or deleting rows or columns from the CSV files 
data.drop(['__fileposition__'], inplace=True, axis=1) 
  
# display  
print("\nCSV Data after deleting the column 'fileposition':\n") 
print(data)
```

I need it to be read in like this

[image]

I have tried seq and I am just not sure of how it needs to be written

Comment: The second column in the original file contains comma-delimited values, you want to split those into separate columns in resulting dataframe?

Comment: Correct and the header is in row 2, so if you look at like an excel doc header is in b2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the CSV into a dataframe, get the header names from the `line` column of the first line. Then drop that row from the df.

The use `.str.split()` to expand that column into multiple columns, discarding the other two columns.

Finally, replace the headers of that df with the headers we got from the first line.

```
data = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')  
headers = data.loc[0].line.split(',')
data.drop(0, inplace=True)
data = data.line.str.split(',', expand=True)
data.rename(columns=dict(enumerate(headers)), inplace=True)
```